# IOS CustomCallout does not get removed from the view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom callout loaded from a xib file.
It loads and displays correctly.
The problem is that the callouts will not remove from the view. 
I recently added the 'tag = 999' so i could try to track the subview, no joy, it never sees a tag with a value of 999.

I have tried every possible 'removeFromSuperview' combination I could find.
The 'handleTap method is getting called ok.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView 
*)view {

    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return;
    }
    UIView *customCalloutView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomXibCallout" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    customCalloutView.tag = 999;
    customCalloutView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    customCalloutView.alpha = 0.9;
    customCalloutView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    CGPoint offset = CGPointAdd(customCalloutView.center,(CGPointMake(-100, -150)));
    customCalloutView.center = offset;
    [view addSubview: customCalloutView];
}


- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {
            if (subView.tag == 999) {
                [subView removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are adding `customCalloutView` as a subview of an `MKAnnotationView` -- ***not*** as a subview of `self.view`. So looping through `self.view.subviews` looking for 999 isn't going to work.

Depending on the hierarchy... if `(MKAnnotationView *)view` is a subview of `(MKMapView *)mapView`, which is a subview of `self.view` ... you *could* try:

```
    UIView *v = [self.view viewWithTag:999];
    [v removeFromSuperview];
```

But.... I think a better route is to know *where* the view is in the hierarchy. In `- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender`, `sender` is the gesture. You can get the view that sent the tap with:

```
    sender.view
```

So, if you know the gesture is being sent by the `MKAnnotationView`, you could keep assigning the 999 tag and change your handler to:

```
    - (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            UIView *v = [sender.view viewWithTag:999];
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Works great. and thanks for the 'heads up' regarding the view hierarchy, I had it stuck in my mind that every view would be accessible from self.view.subviews...

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    MKAnnotationView *av = (MKAnnotationView *)sender.view;
        if (av.tag == 999) {
            [av removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried - gives this error  "No visible @interface for 'UITapGestureRecognizer' declares the selector 'superview' "